# what's the word for a common saying?

Tags: idioms

A common saying like in Hindi "Juldi ka kaam shaitan ka" translation "Anything done in hurry has Satan's reflection in it. "

Something like truism, but it's meaning on google doesn't say what I mean. I want a word for "truism but useful."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about proverb, adage, aphorism, or axiom?

> [Proverb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proverb): a brief popular saying (such as “Too many cooks spoil the broth”) that gives advice about how people should live or that expresses a belief that is generally thought to be true.
>
> [Adage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adage): a traditional saying expressing a common experience or observation.
>
> [Aphorism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aphorism): a short phrase that expresses a true or wise idea.
>
> [Axiom](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/axiom): a generally accepted proposition or principle, sanctioned by experience; maxim.

You can also see [this list of synonyms for *proverb*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/proverb).