# What is the classification for a rote saying like "there but for the grace of God.."?

Tags: phrase-meaning, parts-of-speech, idiom-meaning

I'm not after the proverbial or apotropaic aspects of this, or chant or mantra. Just the "event-centric common utterance" aspects. "Knock on wood" is similar I guess.

There's a moment in time one may say this in conversation with another. And saying it is optional, but commonly understood if done. It is momentary, and passes before long. Definitely a say, and mot likely the same classification of saying exists in other languages.

"I could be wrong, but ..." would be another derived one. Optional, grace-ish and has a moment in time.

Comment: I'd say it's an *expression of relief* like "Phew! That was a close one!" Perhaps a distant cousin to a superstitious saying/action to "ward off the evil eye" like "knock on wood" --closer to "God bless you." It seems distant to "I could be wrong, but..."

Comment: I see it as an acknowledgement that another person's misfortune is not necessarily down to their own moral failings but to unlucky circumstances. [See this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there_but_for_the_grace_of_God_go_I)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the word for a common saying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236812/whats-the-word-for-a-common-saying) (aphorism, adage; also maxim). Or [What do you call a phrase that conveys popular wisdom ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/576342/what-do-you-call-a-phrase-that-conveys-popular-wisdom-a-bird-in-the-hand-is-wor/576343#576343)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree about this being a duplicate regarding "There but for the grace of God," but perhaps the OP wants something broader if "I could be wrong, but ..." is included.

Comment: @DjinTonic There are many, many possible answers here. 'Fixed expressions' is perhaps the broadest with 'idioms' the subset with unusual word-sense and/or grammar. 'Interjections'. "Knock on wood" is a conversational device proffering hope / support (and possibly betraying superstition). "I could be wrong, but ..." is a 'pragmatic marker, subclass modal/hedging'. All these have been covered on ELU in various places.

Comment: Yes, something more general, and "I could be wrong, but", could be a rote introducer to a statement or claim or question.  e.g. "I could be wrong, but isn't Covid19 an airborne disease?" One that isn't strictly necessary.  Is there a hierarchical graph for words/phrases anywhere? Like https://en-word.net but taken further, modeling: expression of relief, superstitious saying, aphorism, adage, maxim, fixed expressions, idioms, interjections, conversational device, hopeful phrase, supporting phrase, pragmatic marker, hedging phrase?